# How to pass multiple values for a parameter in a PIPELINED table function in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have created a function in Oracle with 2 parameters. So when I run the query I want to pass multiple values to each parameter. 
I tried using below changes in the query:

```
coul_1 in ('||par1||') and colu_2 in ('||par2||')
```

But it is not fetching the data.

How to fetch the data when I give multiple values to different declared parameters.Eg:

```
select * from table(fun_name('val1','val2'))

val1 will have a1,a2,a3
val2 will have b1,b2,b3
```

Here is the function code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JOBRUN_STATUS_MONITOR_F(
    own_name IN VARCHAR2,
    status   IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN JOBRUN_STATUS_EDW_1 PIPELINED
IS
  L_TAB JOBRUN_STATUS_MONITOR_EDW_1;
  JR_STATUS NUMBER (38);
  CURSOR jobrun_1_cr (OW_N VARCHAR2, STS VARCHAR2)
  IS
    SELECT *
    FROM JOBRUN A,
      JOBMST B,
      owner C
    WHERE A.JOBMST_ID   = B.JOBMST_ID
    AND C.OWNER_NAME    = OW_N
    AND A.JOBRUN_STATUS = STS ;
 BEGIN V_OWN_NAME := own_name;
  V_STATUS             := status;
  IF jobrun_1_cr%ISOPEN THEN
    CLOSE jobrun_1_cr;
  END IF;
  OPEN jobrun_1_cr (own_name, JR_STATUS);
  CLOSE jobrun_1_cr;
END JOBRUN_STATUS_MONITOR_F; 
/
```

Comment: Show your complete code, it will be easier to help.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JOBRUN_STATUS_MONITOR_F (own_name   IN VARCHAR2, status     IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN JOBRUN_STATUS_EDW_1 PIPELINED
IS   L_TAB        JOBRUN_STATUS_MONITOR_EDW_1;JR_STATUS    NUMBER (38);
CURSOR jobrun_1_cr (OW_N VARCHAR2, STS VARCHAR2) IS
      SELECT * FROM JOBRUN A, JOBMST B, owner C
       WHERE     A.JOBMST_ID = B.JOBMST_ID AND C.OWNER_NAME = OW_N AND A.JOBRUN_STATUS = STS
BEGIN V_OWN_NAME := own_name; V_STATUS := status;IF jobrun_1_cr%ISOPEN THEN CLOSE jobrun_1_cr; END IF; OPEN jobrun_1_cr (own_name, JR_STATUS)  CLOSE jobrun_1_cr; END JOBRUN_STATUS_MONITOR_F;

Comment: ok, and do you pass values to your function as variables or as litteral values?

Comment: Literal values as select * from table(fun_name('multiple_vales','multiple_values'))

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to call the function three times, passing `(a1, b1)`, `(a2, b2)` and `(a3, b3)`. One way would be to generate an inline view containing the values you want to pass, and query it including a call to your function.

Demo pipelined function:

```
create or replace function demo_pipefunc
    ( p_own_name in varchar2
    , p_status   in varchar2 )
    return sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
    pipelined
as
    l_result long;
begin
    for i in 1..3 loop
        l_result := p_own_name ||';'|| p_status ||';'|| i;
        pipe row (l_result);
    end loop;

    return;
end demo_pipefunc;
```

Demo call:

```
with params (own_name, status) as
    ( select 'a1', 'b1' from dual union all
      select 'a2', 'b2' from dual union all
      select 'a3', 'b3' from dual
    )
select t.*
from   params
       cross join table(demo_pipefunc(own_name, status)) t
```

Output:

```
COLUMN_VALUE
a1;b1;1
a1;b1;2
a1;b1;3
a2;b2;1
a2;b2;2
a2;b2;3
a3;b3;1
a3;b3;2
a3;b3;3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JOBRUN_STATUS_MONITOR_F (own_name IN VARCHAR2, status IN VARCHAR2) RETURN JOBRUN_STATUS_EDW_1 PIPELINED
IS L_TAB JOBRUN_STATUS_MONITOR_EDW_1;
JR_STATUS NUMBER (38); 
CURSOR jobrun_1_cr (OW_N VARCHAR2, STS VARCHAR2) 
IS SELECT * 
    FROM JOBRUN A, JOBMST B, owner C 
    WHERE A.JOBMST_ID = B.JOBMST_ID 
    AND C.OWNER_NAME = OW_N 
    AND A.JOBRUN_STATUS = STS;

BEGIN 
    V_OWN_NAME := REPLACE(own_name,'"',''''); 
    V_STATUS := REPLACE(status,'"','''');
    IF jobrun_1_cr%ISOPEN THEN 
        CLOSE jobrun_1_cr; 
    END IF; 

    OPEN jobrun_1_cr (own_name, JR_STATUS);
    CLOSE jobrun_1_cr; 

END JOBRUN_STATUS_MONITOR_F;
```

then call the procedure like this:

```
select * from table(fun_name('"a1","b1","c1"','"a1","b1","c1"'));
```

Your procedure may have other issues with the use of undeclared variables.

Comment: It is not fetching the data..when I am passing multiple parameters to the function.

Comment: I think this nothing to do with the parameters, read here how to use PIPELINED TABLES, your function does not pipe anything nor return anything:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions